# boost to_upper char pointer in one expression

Tags: c++, string, boost

Is it possible to do something like:

```
const char* str = "AaBbCc";
string str_up = boost::to_upper_copy(str); // str_up will be "AABBCC"
```

Last line doesn't compile.

Of course I can as below, but it less "canonical":

```
const char* str = "AaBbCc";

string str_up = str;
boost::to_upper(str_up);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not post the right solution as an answer to the question?

```
 const char* str = "AaBbCc";
 std::string str_up = boost::to_upper_copy(std::string(str));
```

Credits to Konrad.

Comment: Or, equivalently, `std::string str_up = boost::to_upper_copy<std::string>(str);`, credit to UncleBens

Comment: I think that UncleBens posted earlier. (I can't delete own my answer, as I want, because it was accepted.) +1 UncleBens

Answer (score 5):

The declaration of `to_upper_copy` is:

```
template<typename SequenceT> 
SequenceT to_upper_copy(const SequenceT &, const std::locale & = std::locale());
```

From this it should be clear that `SequenceT` can't be a pointer to char, or even a char array, because there's no (good) way how the returned copy could have the same type.

You can explicitly force the type to be `string`:

```
string str_up = boost::to_upper_copy<string>(str);
```

---

Here's explanation what `SequenceT` and `RangeT` mean in the documentation: [String Representation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo/design.html#string_algo.string). In short, neither can be a `const char*`, but `RangeT` arguments accept arrays (`char [X]`).

Answer (score 2):

Sure!

```
inline std::string to_upper_copy(std::string const & src) {
   std::string res(src);
   boost::to_upper(res);
   return res;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to achieve. I want to convert chat* to std::string in upper case in one expression.

Comment: @dimba: Which you can do by calling this function.

Comment: @Erik: Can I do it by boost only, without forcing user to write an auxiliary function?

Comment: @dimba: Sure. Just put the conversion to `string` into the call: `string result = to_upper_copy(string(src))` – but why? And no, there is no direct way since the Boost function expects a *range*, and a C-style string isn’t one.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: thanks. Why not, it's shorter. Do you see with this for some problem, except that some programmers can not love chaining of too functions?

Comment: @dimba If you just use it once, go for it. If you use it all over the place, put it in a function, it helps keep the code clean and lean.